# Select every item in a SQL column into an array, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've hit a little wall in something I'm trying to do.

I have a table, entitled 'projects', in a database in SQL.

My issue is that I can't seem to select every row in a specific column.

This is the code that I've got so far relevant to this question (keep in mind that '$conn' is the connection to the SQL database, and the include command on the second line is just to include that connection):

```
            //CONNECTION FILE   
        include "../include/dbh-inc.php";
        //ASSIGNING QUERY VALUES TO VARIABLES
        $q1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT pid FROM projects;");
        $q2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT ptitle FROM projects;");
        $q3 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT plink FROM projects;");
        //SETTING ARRAYS FROM VARIABLES
        $ids = mysqli_fetch_array($q1);
        $titles = mysqli_fetch_array($q2);
        $links = mysqli_fetch_array($q3);

        mysqli_close($conn);
        file_put_contents("newtest.txt","$titles\n");
        foreach($titles as $title) {
            file_put_contents("newtest.txt","$title\n", FILE_APPEND); //Testing
        }
        if(count($ids) > 0) {
            file_put_contents("TEST.txt","");
            for($i = 0; $i < count($ids)-1; $i+=1) {            
                $count = count($ids);
                $title = $titles[$i];
                $id = $ids[$i];
                $link = $links[$i];
                file_put_contents("TEST.txt","$i: $title, $id ($count), $link\n",FILE_APPEND);
                echo("
                <div class=\"projlink\">
                <a href=\"$link\" style=\"width:190px;height:90px\">
                <h2>$title</h2>
                </a>
                </div>
                ");

            }
        }
        else {
            echo("
                <h2>Nothing here currently!<br>Be patient!</h2>
            ");
        }
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
- Raphael

Comment: Why are you doing multiple queries in the first place? Just do one, and name all the columns whose content you want in the column list of the statement.

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem and what u are trying to do

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry for being vague here. Essentially I'm trying to read every item from an SQL table onto an HTML page to display different pages. Using 'plink' as the reference link and 'ptitle' as the display title.

Comment: Do: `SELECT a,b,c FROM source`. Don't do: `SELECT a FROM source` and then the same for other columns. This is really fundamental stuff. The way you're doing this has no guarantees about order so those results could get arbitrarily jumbled up.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your advice. Other people have suggested the same thing. I'm fairly inexperienced with SQL so I apologise if my mistakes are based off of very fundamental stuff :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only fetching one row with `mysqli_fetch_array`. Also, you can get all columns in one query:

```
$q1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT pid, ptitle, plink FROM projects;");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($q1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If you don't have `mysqli_fetch_all` then:

```
while($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1));
```

Then just loop `$rows` and use the columns:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['pid'] . ' ' . $row['ptitle'] . ' ' . $row['plink'];
}
```

If you really need separate arrays (this is rarely necessary):

```
$ids = array_column($rows, 'pid');
$titles = array_column($rows, 'ptitle');
$links = array_column($rows, 'plink');
```